# Flash drive no longer visible within Windows

Tags: hard-drive, disk-utility, partition

I recently formatted a USB flash drive on my Mac (El-Capitan) and made a bootable Mojave installer drive. It worked great and there were no issues, until I needed to reformat it to use on Windows again. I've formatted the drive as FAT32 with a MBR partition and it reflects as such in the Disk Utility:

Drive:
[image: The screenshot of the drive settings]

Partition:
[image: The screenshot of the partition settings]

Windows Disk Management:
[image: The screenshot of Disk Management in Windows 10]

CMD Diskpart -> list disk:
[image: The screenshot of the disks listed from diskpart.exe]

For some reason, Windows doesn't even recognise that the drive is inserted into the PC. I'd expect to see a 16GB disk with no mountable volumes, instead I just see the same disk-listings that were there before I inserted the drive.

What frustrates me is that I've got experience with partitions and it's not usually rocket-science. The third image shows a hybrid drive with a MacOS partition (for my Macbook Air) that also contains a exFat partition for my media.

I've done this before many times over but can't, for the life of me, figure out why it's not working on this flash drive. Have I missed something really obvious? Am I losing my mind?

Comment: Did you try another USB port on your windows machine?

Comment: @howdytom Yes, I've tried on both front and rear ports on that particular machine as well as my NUC running Windows 7. In fact I had tried on the Win 7 NUC first and just assumed it was Windows acting up!

Comment: Try formating your USB flash drive again as HFS+ volume, first. Afterwards reformat  it as FAT32. Do you see those issues with different USB drives as well?

Comment: @howdytom thanks, I'm trying that now. I've been using Mac & Windows for 5 years now and this is the first time I've encountered that issue

Comment: @howdytom your suggestion is confirmed as working. Please load it as an answer and I'll gladly accept it. Thanks so much for this suggestion!

Comment: I'm glad it worked out. Looks like a disk utility bug

Comment: @howdytom sounds about right, I'll report it to Apple!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try formating your USB flash drive again as HFS+ volume, first. Afterwards reformat it as FAT32.